# Heroku Procfile for worker: python

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to push my discord.py bot to Heroku, but I encountered some errors with the Procfile. My bot is made up of cogs, which are located in a different folder, but I don't know how to specify the directory in Procfile. I have read in some answers that using / works, but it doesn't work for my case. first of all, here is what my project look like:

```
---- cogs
-------- BuiltInCogs.py
-------- Some other cogs that aren't really relevent
Procfile
community_bot.py
```

and my Procfile looks like:

```
worker: python community bot.py 
worker: python cogs/BuiltInCogs.py
```

Note that the first one works, but for the second line, I get this error:

```
2020-10-08T18:09:52.975127+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-10-08T18:09:58.753154+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python cogs/BuiltInCogs.py`
2020-10-08T18:09:59.594842+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-10-08T18:10:01.790915+00:00 app[worker.1]: python: can't open file 'cogs/BuiltInCogs.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2020-10-08T18:10:01.908250+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 2
2020-10-08T18:10:01.983906+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

If bot.py is your main starting file, your cogs should already be called like so:

```
extensions = ['cogs.firstCog', 'cogs.secondCog']
if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    for ext in extensions:
        client.load_extension(ext)
```

Your Procfile only needs to contain the main file for your bot :)

Comment: Hello! Now, when I run community_bot.py, I get an error:

2020-10-09T13:28:34.002326+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.BuiltInCogs' could not be loaded.

Did I do something wrong?